# iOS: CocoaLumberjack: implicit declaration of function is invalid in c99

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoalumberjack

I'm trying to implement CocoaLumberjack on my app as framework but I'm having some issues. Here is my implementation on my AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
    DDFileLogger *fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] init];
    fileLogger.maximumFileSize = 1024 * 1024;
    fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hour rolling
    fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7;
    [DDLog addLogger:fileLogger];
    DDLogWarn(@"blablabla");
    DDLogError(@"Broken sprocket detected!");
    DDLogVerbose(@"User selected file:%@ withSize:%u", @"temp/test/log.txt", 100000);
    return YES;
}
```

In the app delegate has no issues. But in my ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     DDLogError(@"something when wrong!!!"); // <-- implicit declaration of function is invalid in c99
}
```

[image: implicit declaration of function is invalid in c99]
Any of you knows what is wrong or any work around this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: what this means is that the compile can't find a definition for DDLogError. Did you include the cocoa lumberjack header in your viewcontroller.m file?

Comment: @Byron, I add this on the viewController #import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h> and it resolved the C99 error but now I'm getting this error: "use of undeclared identifier ddloglevel"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines:

```
#define LOG_LEVEL_DEF ddLogLevel
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
```

See the **Access and configure the framework** section of the [Getting Started](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#access-and-configure-the-framework) documentation.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work for me. I fixed add this: #import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
#if DEBUG
static const DDLogLevel ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelVerbose;
#else
static const DDLogLevel ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelWarning;
#endif